# Tensorflow: Download and run pretrained VGG or ResNet model

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's start at the beginning. So far I have created and trained small networks in Tensorflow myself. During the training I save my model and get the following files in my directory:

```
model.ckpt.meta
model.ckpt.index
model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
```

Later, I load the model saved in `network_dir` to do some classifications and extract the trainable variables of my model.

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(network_dir + ".meta")
variables = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope="NETWORK")
```

Now I want to work with larger pretrained models like the VGG16 or ResNet and want to use my code to do that. I want to load pretrained models like my own networks as shown above.

On this site, I found many pretrained models:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#pre-trained-models

I downloaded the VGG16 checkpoint and realized that these are only the trained parameters.

I would like to know how or where I can get the saved model or graph structure of these pretrained network? How do I use, for example, the VGG16 checkpoint without `model.ckpt.meta`, `model.ckpt.index` and the `model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next to the weights link, there is link to the code that defines the model. For instance, for VGG16: [Code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/vgg.py). Create the model using the code and restore variables from the checkpoint:

```
import tensorflow as tf

slim = tf.contrib.slim

image = ...  # Define your input somehow, e.g with placeholder
logits, _ = vgg.vgg_16(image)
predictions = tf.argmax(logits, 1)
variables_to_restore = slim.get_variables_to_restore()

saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, "/path/to/model.ckpt")
```

So, the code contained in [vgg.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/vgg.py) will create all the variables for you. Using the tf-slim helper, you can get the list. Then, just follow the usual procedure. There was [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44124138/tensorflow-slim-restore-model-and-predict) on this.

Comment: How do I do that? Can you please be more specific. I am a beginner.

Comment: Thank you very much. I imported the VGG16 code doing `import vgg`. However, I get the following error `NameError: name 'slim' is not defined`. How can I solve this problem to get all the variables of the network?

Comment: `slim = tf.contrib.slim`

Comment: Sorry, for asking such a dumb question.

Comment: Can you please show how I can extract all activations of the VGG16. Normally I get them by doing `activations=tf.get_collection('Activations')`, but this seems not possible here. What is the right way to get the activations?