# Tensorflow: How to load a pre-trained ResNet model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use a pre-trained ResNet model which Tensorflow provides [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim).

First I downloaded the code (`resnet_v1.py`) to reconstruct the model's graph [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/resnet_v1.py). The model's weights (`resnet_v1_50.ckpt`) can be found on the same page [here](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/resnet_v1_50_2016_08_28.tar.gz).

The model can be tested using the following script (`resnet_v1_test.py`) from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/resnet_v1_test.py). However, I have problems to extract the right information from `resnet_v1_test.py`. I don't understand many things that happen in this script. Which are the essential functions to pass a random image through the network? How can I access the weights and activations for further work?

What are the next steps from here? I would appreciate any help!

TL;DR: How can I use the `resnet_v1_test.py` script to perform classification and access weights and activations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow: Error while loading pre-trained ResNet model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54953008/tensorflow-error-while-loading-pre-trained-resnet-model)

Comment: @SzymonMaszke I updated my question. Now it should not a duplicate anymore.

Comment: Do you want to fine-tune the model or use it as-is?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski I want to use the model for predictions and want to work with the weights and activations. I don't want to fine-tune the model.

Comment: Check this for starter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44124138/tensorflow-slim-restore-model-and-predict